# integrate multiple uploads of photos into my posts - django

Tags: python, django

I need to upload an undefined number of images within my posts, currently I can only upload one photo for post
How can I upload multiple images in a single post?
I am attaching the code of my app.

models.py

```
class Casa(models.Model):

    nome_casa = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    descrizione = models.TextField()
    logo_casa = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome_casa

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("visualizza_casa", kwargs={"pk" : self.pk})

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Casa"
        verbose_name_plural = "Case"
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from .models import Casa
from .mixins import StaffMixin



class CreaCasa(StaffMixin, CreateView):
    model = Casa
    fields = '__all__'
    template_name = "inserzioni/crea_casa.html"
    success_url = "/"



def visualizzaCasa(request, pk):
    casa = get_object_or_404(Casa, pk=pk)
    context = {"casa" : casa}
    return render(request, "inserzioni/visualizza_casa.html", context)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see you have model `Casa`, and for now it has only one `ImageField` (`logo_casa`), but you want to add other images to it. 
The easiest way to do that is to create another model (for example `CasaImage`) and add `ImageField` to it. Example:

```
# models.py
class Casa(models.Model):
    nome_casa = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    descrizione = models.TextField()
    logo_casa = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome_casa

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("visualizza_casa", kwargs={"pk" : self.pk})

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Casa"
        verbose_name_plural = "Case"


class CasaImage(models.Model):
    casa = models.ForeignKey(Casa, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField()
```

Notice that I left `logo_casa` field to distinguish logo from other `Casa` images. `CasaImage` has `ForeignKey` field, which represent many to one database relation (you can read more here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/). Parameter `on_delete=models.CASCADE` means that when we will delete `Casa` instance all of related `CasaImages` will be removed automatically.

Comment: hello, thanks for the reply, did this how I have to manage it in the views.py file? good evening

Comment: I provided you `models.py` file, but you will also need to change your `CreaCasa` view. To be more exact: you need to override `form_valid` view method and create `CasaImage` instances there. P.S. sorry, I can't attach code example to the comment, but you can ask another question if you wan't mode details.